# Is it possible to use `--data-urlencode` and `--data-binary` options for the same curl command?

Tags: http, curl, request, http-put

I am using [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) and I would like to execute a HTTP PUT request by sending a `--data-urlencode` string and a `--data-binary` JSON file content. Is it possible to make that in the same `curl` command?

I tried the following

```
curl www.website.org --request PUT -H Content-Type: application/json --data-urlencode "key=sample_string" --data-binary @sample_file.json
```

but it seems do not work as expected: `key=sample_string` and `sample_file.json` content are not send at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things here;

1. Your curl request is missing double quotes for the headers. It should rather be:

```
curl www.website.org --request PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 --data-urlencode "key=sample_string" --data-binary @sample_file.json
```

2. Your content-type is application/json which I hope is not "binary", so you should rather be using an appropriate type.

In any case, you should be able to find the submitted values using a simple php script as follows:

```
$putfp = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$putdata = '';
while($data = fread($putfp, 1024))
    $putdata .= $data;
fclose($putfp);

var_dump($putdata);

echo "---CONTENT_TYPE---\n";
var_dump($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']);
```